# Formatting the date in bash

Tags: shell-script, date

I would like to format the date in bash in a script.

The format is: **2016-10-05T12:18:36.890+02:00**

I'm currently using: `$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: what value do you expect as a result?

Comment: The current date and time UK (BST).

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking is to format date into ISO 8601 format.

```
$(date -Is)
```

`I` for ISO format, `s` for datetime.

Comment: Note that he's apparently looking for ISO 8601 format with millisecond precision and *period* as the decimal separator. Note that `-I` is not a standard option. The only implementation I could find that supports it and subsecond precision was GNU `date` but that's only for nanosecond precision and it always uses a comma as the decimal separator

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `date`:

```
$ date +%FT%T.%3N%:z
2017-06-30T13:00:54.566+01:00
```

With `bash` builtins, the closest you can get is:

```
$ printf -v date '%(%FT%T%z)T' -1
$ printf '%s\n' "${date%??}:${date: -2}"
2017-06-30T13:00:54+01:00
```

as `bash` doesn't support subsecond precision.

With recent versions of `zsh`:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime -s date '%FT%T.%3.%z'
$ printf '%s\n' $date[1,-3]:$date[-2,-1]
2017-06-30T13:00:54.566+01:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
date +%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S%z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zone=$(date +%z)
datetime=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)

iso=$datetime${zone:0:3}:${zone:3:2}

echo $iso
```

https://www.vankuik.nl/2019-04-23_ISO_date_on_macOS

Comment: There's the potential for a race condition there because you're calling `date` twice. For timezones that jump forwards/backwards twice a year you might get a shift between the two calls

Answer (score 0):

The format you are asking for could be written as:

```bash
$ date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z       # similar to your previous +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
2016-10-05T11:18:36+0100

$ date +'%FT%T.%3N%:z'            # shorter with GNU milliseconds
2016-10-05T11:18:36.247+01:00

$ ( t=$EPOCHREALTIME; u=${t#*.};
    printf "%(%FT%T)T.%s%(%z)T\n" "${t%.*}" "${u%???}" )  # Pure bash 5.0+
2016-10-05T11:18:36.450+0100
```